# Vertically aligning block element to image?

Tags: css, image, alignment, block

I'm looking for a way to vertically align a block element to an image. On my site this image would dynamically change in height and width so I'd need the vertical alignment to adapt for whatever the image size is. For example:

```
<img src="photo.jpg" alt="test" />
<div id="box">
</div>

img { float: left; }

#box { float: right; width: 200px; height: 150px; background-color: #666; }
```

So I'd want this div to vertically align itself to the image. How can this be done?
Thanks.

Comment: Vertically align how? centered? Top? Bottom?

Comment: Yes, centered. Sorry if I didn't convey that originally.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to add a couple layers of wrapper-divs. The first layer is set to `white-space: nowrap` and `max-width:50%` which means that the elements inside can't wrap, and are constrained to 50% of the width of the parent.

Then you set the white space back to normal, and make the second layer `display:inline-block` so that these divs have to play by text alignment rules. Then you set *both* of them to `vertical-align:middle;` Just one won't work because vertical align is relative to the **baseline** of the text, not the containing block element.

So in this way we have constrained ourselves to one line of "text", composed of two div elements both aligned such their middle is at the text baseline, and ensured that their size must be no more than 50% of the parent container.

**EDIT:** I discovered after little more playing that you need to add some max-width:100% to keep the image from pushing the text out the right hand side.

**EDIT 2:** I should have mentioned that this requires IE-8 standards mode, added meta-equiv to tell IE-8 to behave itself, but giving a proper doctype or sending an http response header can achieve the same thing google IE8 standards mode for all that stuff.

```
<html >  
  <head>  
    <title>Test</title>  
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      .wrapper1 {
        white-space:nowrap;
        max-width:50%;
      }
      .wrapper2 {
        white-space:normal;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        max-width:100%;
      }
      .variable-img {
        max-width:100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>  
  <body>  
  <div class="wrapper1">
    <div class="wrapper2">
      <img class="variable-img" src="test.png">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper2">
      <div id="box">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
        aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
        ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
        esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: If it solved your problem please mark it as the correct answer. (You will get +2 reputation for doing this). If you are particularly happy you can up-vote it too.