# Width 100% More than 100% of Screen

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm creating a narrow stylesheet for a responsive website. It is set to take affect when the browser is between 0px and 400px wide. (See Below)

```
<link href="css/narrow.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 400px)" />
```

My goal is to have the content be centered in the browser at all times, no matter what the dimensions are. Problem is, the wrapper div seems to stay at 400px wide, and does not respond to the browser width even though the wrapper div is set to 100%.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper"> <!-- Start Wrapper -->

        <div id="sidebar"> <!-- Start Sidebar -->
        </div> <!-- End Sidebar -->

        <div id="mainContent"> <!-- Start Main Content -->

            <div id="about"> <!-- Start About -->
            </div> <!-- End About -->

            <div id="services">  <!-- Start Services --> 
                 <div id="servicesWrapper"> 
                 </div>
            </div> <!-- End Services -->

            <div id="work"> <!-- Start Work -->
            </div> <!-- End Work -->

            <div id="contact"> <!-- Start Contact -->
            </div> <!-- End Contact -->

        </div> <!-- End Main Content -->


    </div> <!-- End Wrapper -->
    </body>
```

Here is the CSS

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: inherit;
    height: 300px;
    top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
}

#mainContent {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#about {
    width: 65%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-height: 600px;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 350px;
    z-index: 1; 
}

#services {
    width: 65%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    min-height: 600px;
    max-height: 100%;
}

#work {
    width: 65%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    height: 600px;
    max-height: 100%;
}

#contact {
    width: 65%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    height: 600px;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: you have it set to 100%, so if the width is 400 px, the wrapper will default to 400px, what is the width of the screen you are testing this on?

Comment: I am using Firefox, and when I make the browser less than 400px, it just cuts off the wrapper div and everything inside it.

Comment: One problem I see is `font-size: 100%; font: inherit;`. You should decide which of those two you want.

Answer (score 1):

That is not your problem. Your problem is that you are trying to use **text**-align to center a **block** element. If you want a div to be effected by text-align, you need to set `display:inline-block;` on it.

See [Vertically aligning block element to image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072258/vertically-aligning-block-element-to-image) for more details on this (for the vertical case, there but the same idea applies)

Comment: Thanks Gus,I just applied that to my CSS. However, my main issue is that my wrapper div seems to be stuck at 400px. When I resize the browser to anything smaller than 400px, everything gets cut off.

Answer (score 1):

First, `text-align: center` only works on inline elements. Center the containing element `#wrapper` using your margins `margin: 0 auto`. This won't do a whole lot if your width is 100%.

Your media query (correct me if I am wrong) does not require a min-width, only the max-width property. The max-width is saying, "Don't use this stylesheet if the width is larger than 400px."

Based on my tests, your code above with my small changes, works in Chrome, FireFox, and IE9 (though not IE8 and below).

Comment: Thanks Akaishen,

I made these corrections, but it still did not work. It made my sidebar div flush right and about half the size of the browser width.

Comment: What version of FireFox are you using? I'd like to replicate what you are seeing, though as I said before, everything looks correct on my side.

Comment: Also, I created a separate html document to fool around with. I noticed that when the browser gets below 400px wide, everything gets cut off. I am NOT using any media queries for this test HTML. The version of Firefox I am using is 10.0.1 

Here is the HTML:
<div id="wrapper">

 <div id="content">
    
     <p>TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST</p>
        
    </div>

</div>
</body>

Here is the CSS:

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#0F0;
  height: 500px;
 }
 
 #content {
  width: 65%;  
 }

Comment: I've uploaded my version to: so.eleista.com/martin/stackoverflow.html (I just registered the sub-domain, so it may not work immediately). My media query is set at 800px instead of 400px for testing purposes. Despite having enough content, when I shrink the window, the width shrinks just fine and the content wraps as it should (no horizontal scrollbars). The only thing that gets 'cutoff' is where the #sidebar is fixed at the top of the screen over the content. However, that has nothing to do with the question, so I'm assuming that's intentional. Could you link to your example?

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue on your website. When I shrink the page using FF 10.0.1, once the page hits the 400px mark, the content is centered for #about and more-or-less left aligned on #services and #work. If you want #services and #work to be centered, set their horizontal margins to auto. You may also want to change the width from 65% as that seems a bit small when all you have is 400px or less to view. I'd set your #sidebar to 100% width once the screen is < 400px. What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Thanks Akaishen. Strange, I wonder why it is behaving that way on my computer. I'm running Lion 10.7.2, maybe that has something to do with it? The expected behavior is for everything to be centered and fluid.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7. If you'd like, you could take a screenshot to show me exactly what you are seeing. When I owned a Mac, I came across issues that non-mac users didn't have. This may or may not be one of those, though I'd be interested in helping if you'd like to.

Comment: Thanks again, Akaishen. Here is a screen shot. http://oi43.tinypic.com/122gg9d.jpg

Comment: That is interesting. On Windows 7, the content does not get cutoff as your screenshot shows. I'd show this in a screenshot, though your website appears to be down. At the very least, we know that there is a difference between Windows 7 FF 10.0.1 and Mac OSX FF 10.0.1. Alas, I'm not sure how I can assist you further. If you want to make the site live again, I could get you a screenshot and you can open a new question about why the two versions are different. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! I am temporally hosting it with 000webhost for testing purposes. Thing is, it's a free service so that is probably why the site is down. Anyways, glad to know that that it at least works in most browsers as of now.