# Getting images to align horizontally correctly

Tags: html, css

Here's the page I'm working on:

http://artificialmarketingsolutions.com/step-1-choose-your-route/

I have them in a container with a set height, but they're going beyond that height. Additionally, they're spilling into the content area and overlapping, instead of simply bumping the current content down.

Thanks for any tips!

Jesus I'm an idiot! Here's the code:

CSS:

```
.steps {
   width: 500px;
   height: 70px;
   display: block;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="steps">
  <a href="http://www.advantagegrandcanyon.com"><img src="http://artificialmarketingsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/BackButton.png"></a>
  <img src="http://artificialmarketingsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Step1.png">
  <a href="http://www.artificialmarketingsolutions.com/step-2-choose-your-trip-duration"><img src="http://artificialmarketingsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/NEXT.png"></a>
</div>
```

Code below the images:

```
<a href="http://artificialmarketingsolutions.com/grand-canyon-routes/full-grand-canyon/"><img class="imgs alignnone size-full wp-image-27" alt="FullGrand" src="http://artificialmarketingsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/FullGrand.jpg" width="274" height="204" /></a>
<strong>Full Grand Canyon Trip Features:​</strong>
<ul>
    <li>Longest Route Option​</li>
    <li>Up to 187, 225 or 279 River Miles​</li>
    <li>Motorized Trips from 6-10 Days</li>
    <li>​Non Motorized Trips  from 10-18 Days</li>
    <li>No Mandatory Hiking In or Out</li>
    <li>Over 104 Rapids</li>
    <li>All Raft Types Available​</li>
</ul>
Full canyon river trips begin at Lees Ferry, river mile zero, and continue downstream to one of the "take out" or departure points.  These take-out points are as follows: The Whitmore Helipad at river mile 187, the Diamond Creek Road at river mile 225, a take-out via jetboat ride across Lake Mead beginning just below Separation Canyon at river mile 240 or Pearce Ferry river mile 279.


</div>
<div id="middle">

<a href="http://artificialmarketingsolutions.com/grand-canyon-routes/upper-grand-canyon/"><img class="imgs alignnone size-full wp-image-29" alt="UpperGrand" src="http://artificialmarketingsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/UpperGrand.jpg" width="274" height="204" /></a>

<strong>Upper Canyon Trip Features:​</strong>
<ul>
    <li>Shortest Route Option​</li>
    <li>89 River Miles</li>
    <li>Motorized Trips 3-5 Days</li>
    <li>Non Motorized Trips 5-8 Days​</li>
    <li>Must Hike out 7.5-10 miles</li>
    <li>Over 41 Rapids</li>
    <li>All Raft Types Available</li>
</ul>
Running from Lees Ferry to Phantom Ranch in the heart of the Grand Canyon, the upper portion is 89 miles long. Upon leaving Lees Ferry, you will quickly enter Marble Canyon. Within a few miles, the first signs of the fascinating geology of the canyon begin to appear as the Kaibab and Toroweap formations make their appearance, followed by Coconino Sandstone​.


</div>
<div id="right-side">

<a href="http://artificialmarketingsolutions.com/grand-canyon-routes/lower-grand-canyon/"><img class="imgs alignnone size-full wp-image-28" alt="LowerGrand" src="http://artificialmarketingsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/LowerGrand.jpg" width="274" height="204" /></a>
<strong>Lower Canyon Trip Features:​</strong>
<ul>
    <li>Multiple Trip Length Options​</li>
    <li>​98, 136 or 190 River Miles</li>
    <li>Motorized Trips 5-6 Days​</li>
    <li>Non Motorized Trips 7-10 Days</li>
    <li>Must Hike in 7.5-10 miles</li>
    <li>Over 60 Rapids</li>
    <li>All Raft Types Available</li>
</ul>
Your trip will begin at the South Rim of the Grand Canyon.  All passengers going on lower canyon trips spend part of day 1 hiking down Bright Angel Trail to Phantom Ranch (approx. 10 Miles) or to Pipe Creek Beach (approx. 7.5 Miles) depending on the outfitter’s exact meeting point. ​


</div>

<div id="info-container" style="width:100%; height: 100%; display: inline-block;">
<div id="left-info">
  <a href="http://artificialmarketingsolutions.com/grand-canyon-routes/full-grand-canyon/">More Info</a>
  </div>
<div id="middle-info">
  <a href="http://artificialmarketingsolutions.com/grand-canyon-routes/upper-grand-canyon/">More Info</a>
  </div>
<div id="right-info">
  <a href="http://artificialmarketingsolutions.com/grand-canyon-routes/lower-grand-canyon/">More Info</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We can't understand the meaning of *them* and *they*? please specify where actually the problem is? it would be very nice if you have some code to show here

Comment: First tip: make a jsfiddle to isolate the problem (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Oops – sorry! Edited post to include code.

Comment: If you mean the text that's not lined up below those images, (in firefox) it seems you have a <br> in two out of three text blocks..

Comment: Hmm, don't think so... added that code.

Comment: Is it the text lining up, or the arrows hanging over the map images you are trying to solve?

Comment: the arrows hanging. I want the arrows to be horizontal, like on this page: http://www.advantagegrandcanyon.com/#!step-grand-canyon-routes/c1dj2

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072258/vertically-aligning-block-element-to-image/9083007#9083007

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
<div class="steps">
  <a href="http://www.advantagegrandcanyon.com"><img src="http://artificialmarketingsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/BackButton.png"></a><!--br /-->
  <img src="http://artificialmarketingsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Step1.png"><!--br /-->
  <a href="http://www.artificialmarketingsolutions.com/step-2-choose-your-trip-duration"><img src="http://artificialmarketingsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/NEXT.png"></a>
</div>
```

What you should do is simply remove those `<br />` tags because they're causing the arrows to appear on a new line. Already commented them out in the code above so you can take a look at what I'm talking about.

Next you might also want to float those arrows if you want them at either side.

**CSS**

```
.steps a{
    float:right;
}
.steps a:first-child{
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
.steps {
   width: 500px;
   height: 70px;
   clear:both !important;
   display: block;
   padding: 10px;
}
```